# XAML binding windows phone template

Tags: xaml, binding, windows-phone, datatemplate

I have a page showing pics with text below it (like a Tile),

In xaml I simply bind to a image and text property, and then in the c# code I set the listbox's itemssource to my specific data.

Now the problem is there are 9 pics with text below them displaying, which gets created dynamically, but I want the first pic to only display the pic and not the text.

So  my question is, is it possible to (in xaml) access the specific item in the source, for example:
            if(datasource.obj.name =="watever")
            {
              code to only show pic
            }
            else
            {
              show pic and text
            }

Can I try something else maybe?

Any feedback would be appreciated

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot do that via XAML, but you can apply Converters in your xaml. That way you can "investigate" if the item is the first one, just to hide the text.